# Why OPENXML only returns one element

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, openxml

Can somebody explain me why this T-SQL code only returns one row with the value "1"? I was expecting to get two rows ("1" and "2"). Am I missing something here?

```
DECLARE @XMLDoc2 XML
SELECT @XMLDoc2 = '<ids><id>1</id><id>2</id></ids>'

DECLARE @handle2 INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle2 OUTPUT, @XMLDoc2

SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@handle2, '/ids', 2) WITH (id INT 'id') 

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle2
```

**NOTE**: I'm using SQL Server 2008

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you use the new .nodes() method on XML variables in SQL Server 2005 and up??

```
DECLARE @XMLDoc2 XML
SELECT @XMLDoc2 = '<ids><id>1</id><id>2</id></ids>'


SELECT
   ids.id.value('.', 'int') 'id'
FROM 
   @xmldoc2.nodes('/ids/id') ids(id)
```

This gives me the '1' and '2' value as expected.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and I found the answer on another site. You have to use '/ids/id' instead of '/ids' and then use '.' in the WITH clause.

```
DECLARE @XMLDoc2 XML 
SELECT @XMLDoc2 = '<ids><id>1</id><id>2</id></ids>' 

DECLARE @handle2 INT 

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle2 OUTPUT, @XMLDoc2 

SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@handle2, '/ids/id', 2) WITH (id INT '.')  

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle2
```

Answer (score 7):

Forget about the openxml non-sense, is slow, cumbersome, unusable and bad all around. Use the [XML methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx), they're fast, intuitive, user friendly and oozing with goodness:

```
DECLARE @XMLDoc2 XML
SELECT @XMLDoc2 = '<ids><id>1</id><id>2</id></ids>'

select x.value(N'.', N'int') as id
from @XMLDoc2.nodes(N'/ids/id') t(x);
```

Comment: Well, I was in a big hurry to roll out 'oozing with goodness', I like the sound of it ;)

Comment: `t.x.value` or `x.value`, both work (I even tested before I posted!). `t` is a table alias in this context and is not required, because there is only one possible `x` so the name can be resolved unambiguosly.

Comment: @Remus: ah, okay - the tutorial I used to learn this SQL XML stuff, they never mentioned that the table alias was optional - good to know, though!

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @XMLDoc2 XML
SELECT @XMLDoc2 = '<ids><id>1</id><id>2</id></ids>'
DECLARE @handle2 INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle2 OUTPUT, @XMLDoc2
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@handle2, '/ids/id', 2) WITH (id INT '.') 
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is to ids so id is an attribute of ids but this is not the case so you need to
specify the xpath by going up the tree using .. then specify the node. a node is specified by `../id` and an attribute by `../@whatever`

```
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@handle2, '/ids', 2) WITH (id INT '../id')
```